# Get data attribute of jQuery UI Selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, list

I have a jQuery UI selectable list: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

each row I generate has a unique ID that looks like:

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="5">test</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="6">adfsg</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="7">ghj</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="8">fhjk</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="9">fhn</li>
</ol>
```

What I need to do is loop through the list and get the data-userid attribute value for ones that are selected.

My JS so far is just this:

```
$('#selectable').selectable().bind("selectableselected",function(event,ui)
{

});
```

which if I do a `console.log(ui.selected)`, I get the whole HTML string. I think I am going about this the wrong way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the class for a selected item would be ui-selected:

```
$('#selectable .ui-widget-content.ui-selected').each(function(index) {
     alert($(this).attr('data-userid'));
});
```

Comment: yea that currently gets ALL the userids, but very close!

Answer (score 3):

The plugin adds a `.ui-selected` class for selected items so it's pretty easy to get the selected items.

The [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function allows to return a (sort-of) array with a callback to return the data:

```
var ids = $('#selectable .ui-selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('userid');
});

// to get a pure javascript array
ids.toArray();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/hfgq7/) to play with.

Comment: I have added some css and a more helpful alert to the fiddle.